# Change steam tray icon back to default

Tags: steam, system-tray

I have used this blog article http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/get-ubuntu-mono-icons-for-steam-ubuntu.html to change the default tray steam icon to the one used in the article for Ubuntu-mono-dark. now I cant seem to change back to the default icon. the icon which is used for Ubuntu-mono-dark clashes with my new theme, where I cant seem to see the steam icon very well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/48/steam_tray.png
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache --ignore-theme-index -f /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
```

Or if you did the tutorial for the Light theme:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/48/steam_tray.png
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache --ignore-theme-index -f /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
```

Maybe using the parameter `--force` in the `gtk-update-icon-cache` could help also.

Comment: thank you @Leopoldo Pla that didnt work, I even removed every steam  that contain the word steam from my system and than updated the cache but it still didnt remove the icon.

Comment: Have you tried to install Steam now that you have uninstalled all Steam files of your system? Maybe if you install the program now it overrides the files that maybe you missed or refreshes the caches.

Comment: I reinstalled Steam, that tray icon is their. another thing, I don't think I uninstalled steam completely because the my account is already logged in.

Comment: Then, search for a Steam folder in you home directory or inside .local (is hidden inside the home directory) and delete it (backup the games if you don't want to download them later)

Comment: I just redid anything plus the new advice you gave, still no luck. thanks anyway.